# Pandas changing values when inferring dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I came across the following problem:

I have this file which is structured as a `jsonlines` file:

```
{"id": 1, "uuid": "1344800117571260417"}
{"id": 2, "uuid": "1344900117571260918"}
```

If I try to read it with Pandas like this:

`df = pd.read_json('file.jsonl', orient='records', lines=True)`

I get the following `DataFrame`:

```
   id                 uuid
0   1  1344800117571260416
1   2  1344900117571260928
```

But the `uuid` has different values, I am thinking of some overflow happening here, but I am not sure. The type inferred by `pandas` for that column is `int64`, but `np.iinfo(np.int64).max` is `9223372036854775807`, which is way higher than the values from the `uuid` column.

An immediate solution to this problem is to disable inferring the types, like `pd.read_json(..., dtype=False)`, but I am curious about this unexpected behavior, does anyone know why this is happening?

BTW, I am using `pandas` version `1.0.1` and `python` version `3.7.6`.

Comment: `int(float("1344900117571260918"))` is `1344900117571260928` . I assume pandas first uses floats and afterwards converts it to int - so precision is lost.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, that is mentioned in the post

Comment: I think this worth filling for a bug on [Pandas GitHub project](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas)

Comment: @AndrejKesely interesting, if that's the way it's working it could lead to potential problems, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, `pandas` does `int(float(x))`, which is the reason of the bug. I filed a ticket to report the bug, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40992).

Comment: Which has been marked as a dupe of a 3-yr old [issue #20608 - read_json reads large integers as strings incorrectly if dtype not explicitly mentioned](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20608) which is still open; and inactive for a year now.